# specify commands to run after conda create from yml file

Tags: anaconda, conda

I have a `environment.yml` file which I used to create a Python environment using:

`conda env create --file environment.yml`.

After the environment is created, I need to perform some operations (such as registering a kernel with jupiter-lab):

`ipython kernel install --name=to_the_edge`

I would like to embed one or more shell commands to run "post install" so that the setup is self-contained within the .yml file.  Is there a way to do this?  Or is there a different way within conda to get close to what I'm after?

I would also like a way to specify shell commands to be run after `conda activate`, but that's a secondary hope.

Maybe this isn't possible because conda works cross platform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't really possible with standard Conda commands, but there are some options to obtain such functionality.

### Jupyter and Conda

The best practice for Jupyter and Conda is to have a single env that has `jupyter` installed and also has `nb_conda_kernels`. You always launch `jupyter notebook` from this env. The `nb_conda_kernels` package enables Jupyter to automatically detect any other envs that have `ipykernel` (or other language equivalents, e.g., `r-irkernel`). Hence, you don't need any additional registration, but simply need to include `ipykernel` in the YAML. See [the docs for `nb_conda_kernels`](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels#nb_conda_kernels).

### Running scripts at install

This cannot be done from a YAML. However, you could build your own custom package that does this at install time and then include that in your YAML. You would have to provide the `.sh`, `.bat`, etc. to run the commands. See [the documentation on adding pre-link, post-link, and unlinked scripts to a package recipe](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/link-scripts.html).

Through this route, you can also [add activate and deactivate scripts](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/activate-scripts.html) that are run when the env is activated and deactivated, respectively. You can also add such scripts manually, i.e., without a custom package. For example, [the docs show how to define environment variables](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#saving-environment-variables) at activation, but you can run arbitrary scripts.